# having some trouble writing and removing punctuation python

Tags: python-3.x

so i'm trying to clean up a file for my assignment by converting to lowercases and removing punctuations.

content:

I'm a fan of soft serve ice cream and Guptill's Coney Express has delicious ice cream with many flavors.  I've tried Kurver Kreme in Colonie, Tastee Freeze in Delmar and Country Drive Inn in Clifton Park, but I think that this place has the best soft serve ice cream.  The portions are generous and the taste is very rich.  For example, the brownie sundae is decadently delicious but likely too much for one person.  They also have cupcake sundaes which I am looking to try soon!
The nurses here were very  attentive and wonderful. I was able to have the same surgical nurse that I had for another procedure a few years ago. The anesthesiologist listened to my concerns and acting skillfully and compassionately. I felt well taken care of there.
Pretty great!  Okay, so this place is obviously not Vegan since they have a bunch of cheese and egg offerings, BUT I see that they do offer plenty of vegan alternatives.\n\nI was sort of skeptical being here because the prices were pretty hefty, I felt.  I guess it looked like a fast-food/diner joint, but it charged a little more. \n\nAnyway, their homemade hot sauce is AMAZING.  I got the eggs benedict for dinner and J got an omelet.  Both were really good.  I do love their homefries.. but the next time I come here, I want onion rings or fries.  Those onion rings looked amazing.\n\nLastly, the food came relatively quickly.\n\nNot a fan of the service.  They tried to seat us at this edge facing the stoves, without asking, so I asked for a booth.  Then at the booth, the server didn't refill waters very well but didn't feel bad emphasizing over and over whether or not we wanted their $5-7 desserts.  Honestly, a slice of pie for $6.50?  Veggie Galaxy, you are t r i p p i n !\n\nBut great food! (especially breaky!)
The Tale of the 4-Starred, Up Close and Personal Bar.\n\nThe Back Abbey is a bar that is located in the charming West Village part of Claremont. The area resembles the old shopping strip-meets-new shopping strip of San Luis Obispo.  What they did -- or so I've been told -- is that they've managed to preserve the old strip, leaving it looking the way it presumably did in the 70s.  Rhino Records is located in the older part.  The Back Abbey in the new part.  Both distinct areas of their aesthetic and consumer pull. \n\nThe Back Abbey specializes in Belgian draft beer.  They carry some German and English beer, as well.\n\nWow, the selection of beer. Let me tell you! A lof of them I have never heard of. I tasted the Augustijn (Belgian) and the Hofbrau Original (German).  Both were good, but I prefer the Hofbrau.They come in different sized glasses, with the Hofbrau coming in a long glass. The Augustijn was $9, and the Hofbrau $6. The Hofbrau came in the larger glass, so the Augustijn must be considered some premium brew for it to be in a smaller glass and come knocking down doors at a mighty $9.  \n\nI liked the overall aesthetics of the place. There is an up-close-and-personal feel to the bar. Along with the standard bar and barstools set-up, there's a long table that goes from one end of the bar to the other. People sit across from each other and, since the tables are not wide, you're not far at all from the person sitting in front of you. Like I wrote earlier, up close and personal is what this bar has going for it.\n\nThey have a food menu, as well. Above their draft selection of beer, they have a chalkboard placed high up with a list of what they serve. For those veggies among us, they even make a veggie burger.\n\nLastly, the patrons all seem to know each other. Maybe it's the small town mentality. But it's not exactly a backwards, hick town. It's very much modern in certain ways, and people just love to talk. Couple that with brew, and there's a lot of talk going on.\n\nI had a discussion with someone at the bar, who bartends at a bar not too far from The Back Abbey, and he told me that the Augustijn is the oldest beer recipe known to man. (Ah, ok. Old is vintage. Vintage is expensive. Thus, Augustijn is expensive.  And two + two = four. I got this down, partna'.)   Again, can we give it up for \
As a vegan, I try to support places that are not wholly vegetarian, but that made the effort to put a vegetarian section on their menu, to show them that it's worth keeping. Thai Singha House does indeed have a section of their menu that reads vegetarian, but, unfortunately, their definition of vegetarian is different from mine.\n\nAll of the vegetarian curries, I was fortunately informed upon asking, do indeed contain fish sauce, which is an ingredient in the curry itself, and cannot be omitted.\n\nMy server suggested the pad thai as a fish-free vegetarian alternative, which I ordered, holding the egg. When it arrived, there appeared to be tofu in there and no egg, which was a good sign. But after a few blind, trusting bites I quickly realized that there was also chicken or pork mixed in as well. My server graciously took it back and honored my request for a house salad, of which I wasn't charged.\n\nI don't blame Thai Singha House for not understanding the definition of vegetarian (sadly, I know a few \
On a recent visit to SLO, I got taken out to the Natural Cafe, which bears a distinct resemblance to some of the places I remember from growing up in Berkeley. Very natural woodsy, with just enough sprouts on the sandwich to add a little crunch.  It's casual, with counter service only.\n\nMy turkey burger was not too dry, but the guacamole and special sauce helped it along in the moistness department. I didn't walk away from the meal feeling all gross and over full like you would with a normal burger and fries.  Yeah for whole grains and veggies!
Great place! \n\nI have to say the menu and the outdoor seating keep us coming back.  The food is good -- had breakfast both times but some friends had lunch items. Definitely a great selection.  We've been at off-peak times so no waiting and better service. \n\nAll in all, it's no DZ Akins but it's definitely worth trying!
Went to Rebecca's Cafe today during my lunch break today.  I have to say, my sandwich was delicious!  I had a Chicken Caprese panini (grilled chicken, tomato, mozzarella cheese, spinach, and balsamic vinaigrette).  The staff was friendly and the service was quick, however the price is a little high for my taste ($7 or so for the sandwich only).  Overall, I would definitely go back to try some different items (or even get the same sandwich), but it won't be too often.
The only thing I've ever eaten at Time-Out is their ice cream cookie sandwich thing, and that's really all I need.  It's about a half-gallon of ice cream sandwiched between two large-ish chocolate chip cookies.  I don't know if they make it, or if it comes off a truck, or what... but it's frozen so solid you usually have to wait a few minutes before chowing down so you don't break a tooth.\n\nIf nothing else, they are one of the few old standards on Franklin Street that have not succumbed to the high-end shopping takeover, so they are worth being excited about.\n\nDo watch out for drunken Tarheels, though.  This place has more disgusting drunkenness issues late at night than any bar I've been in.
Pros: Very clean and pretty little place. Really sweet-natured and attentive servers. Clean bathrooms (Haha it says a lot, ok?) Reasonable prices \n\nCons: Pho broth started ok but after a while starts to taste bitter and weird and left my mouth really dry. Meat is kinda chewy.\n\nThis place could have been SO AWESOME. A pho place so close to campus is one of those \
This is my favorite place of all time. I've driven from LA to SLO just to eat here. The barbecue sauce is AMAZING! Everything here is AMAZING! I can never decide what to get when I go here. Here's what I rotate between; tri tip sandwich, chicken wings and the ABC burger. Their fries are delicious also! Wings are fried and spicy. ABC burger is ten times more delicious then In N Out. I don't even know what to say about the trip tip sandwich. Words can not describe it. If you are a meat eater, you'll love it. It's bread, bbq sauce and like 2 inches of steak. Just amazing! My mouth is watering trying to describe the food.
After enduring years of crappy, undercooked, bad pizza in and around Ann Arbor (a la pizza house, cottage inn, and the like), Silvio's brings real pizza to town. Real pizza should be thin, have a crispy, bubbly, sourdough crust and be full of flavor, not grease, and this is the only place to get it.\n\nDon't be fooled by the \
The average rating for this place is right on point: a-ok.  We came here with a relatively large group on a Friday night a little after ten o'clock.  The first floor of the place was packed, but we found plenty of space upstairs in the corner, which is a pretty weird room considering how removed it is from everything.  Or waiter was good about taking everyone's drink orders and being patient about it, though at one point he gave the right drinks to the wrong people.  He was also cool about serving us while we played a stupid game with post its on our foreheads.  We didn't order any food, but I was impressed that their kitchen is open so late and the menu is pretty big.  \n\nWe were having a fun time until the band came on down stairs.  The blaring sound was inescapable, even though we were kind of removed from where everything was happening.  The music was so loud it was almost impossible to hear what anyone was saying right next to you.  In case you're planning to pay with Discover, they DO accept it; not so cooperative on the check splitting though.
For the grand finale of my LA trip, we head over to Firestone Grill immediately after Splash Cafe.\n\nI like this place for many reasons.  Obviously the tri-tip sandwich was just off da hook delicious even after clam chowder & calamari literally 5 mins ago.  I also think this is one of the largest, most laid back sports bar/grills I've been to.  The ladies at the register and the bartenders were very friendly in answering my questions.  There is a large dining area inside and the humongous patio outside, but I don't doubt that people may end up spilling onto the sidewalk during game days as it was already quite packed for a Sunday evening.  Despite the noise factor, I felt there was good energy from everyone and I was pretty comfortable.  They have plenty of wide screen LCD TVs hung along the walls for your viewing pleasure (and the picture is clear :P).  I don't think they have servers so you have to walk up to the counter or bar for service.  Not a big deal to me IMO.  \n\nSome might say that it was premature to give this a 5 star rating, but I have faith that the next time I visit (and I will go back), I will not be disappointed.
I've used this service for years.  The best parts are that it tends to be on time and that there are bike racks on the front of the buses.  Unfortunately the drivers must navigate roads filled with undergraduates on bicycles who think they are immortal.  I've seen some close calls, but the drivers get serious kudos for being able to drive in that environment all day.\n\nThe drivers tend to be helpful and friendly, though some of them don't speak excellent English.  There are a few routes I get a bit car-sick on, but that is due to the twisty roads and frequent stopping-accelerating.  \n\nThe routes change, especially if there is construction going on.  Make sure you check to see what is running during the summer and holidays.  I've waited for shuttles that weren't going to come for days before.
Cannot believe how highly rated this place is, wow. Takes forever for them to get orders out even when its super slow. Our pizza took something like 65 minutes from the time we ordered it. Now i will wait that long if the pizza is going to be amazing, like at pizza popilis down in greek town. But this pizza was average at best. I think that the gluten free offerings are great but I really expected alot more. Great renovations btw the place looks amazing.
We went here a few weeks ago on the premiere weekend of Horrible Bosses.  Loved that movie!  \nMy wife wanted to come to a real movie theater that was more of a classic than one of these \
One of the best nights of my life. Hands down.\n\nIt was just amazing... The amount of people that gathered all for the same thing, The music pumping through your body everywhere you walked, The day turned to night, and the fireworks that illuminated the sky as you danced without a care to the blissful beats of Deadmau5 and others. It was a night that I will never forget.\n\nYes, it was not perfect, but what event of that size ever has been. I mean you don't show up to the largest rave in america and not expect there to be a shit load of people there. The numbers have been increasing every year, so why would this one be any different? If not, it would only be even bigger, since the biggest rising dance artist of the year, and the biggest name in trance are headlining...\n\nAnd as for all that crap about fence jumping and people getting hurt, and that one girl even died!.. OK, my condolences go out to that girls family, having a death in the family is hard, i cant even imagine it being your child.... BUT you cannot blame her taking drugs on an event, any more than video-games for kids shooting other kids. Its their own ignorance and apathy. As for all those people who got hurt. More than likely their own fault. Some 250 out of 180,000 people messed up, and now theres this huge dim view on raves. Cause there have been less riots and fights due to hockey, or football, or basketball, etc. right? (note: sarcasm above)\n\nMy final word/opinion: Definitely the best massive I've ever been to. Just as good, if not better than last year! Can't wait for next year!
I was in a desperate need of a good falafel and once again Yelp didn't let me down.\n\nOnce in the small deliciously smelling restaurant, I decided to go with the lamb gyro. I read many good things and decided to try it out, and was praying it wouldn't turn my entire mouth yellow(as stated by a few yelpers). \n\nI am happy to report that the gyro was deliciously seasoned and had huge pieces of lamb wrapped up inside. I couldn't tell you if my mouth turned yellow because I made it a point to not

```
file_input = open('yelp.dat', 'r')


convert_lowercase = [line.lower() for line in file_input]
with open('yelp.dat', 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(sorted(convert_lowercase))


import string
remove = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '\n ' + string.punctuation))
with open('yelp.dat') as file_input:
    f = file_input.read()translate(remove)
```

i ran it but i checked the file there's still punctuation. where did i go wrong?

Comment: You forgot to `read()` the file object on the first line. You should also do `file_input.close()` somewhere in your code :)

Comment: sorry, i didn't quite understand :( are you able to show me an example? really new to programming so i'm struggling to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple issues I noticed.
In your code, you open your file with `file_input = open("file", "r")`. This opens the file in read mode, but you don't receive the contents of this file until you do `file_input.read()`. Additionally, when using `open()` without a context manager, you should close the file with `file_input.close()`.  Some code that would work:

```
import string
file_input = open("yelp.dat", "r")
file_content = file_input.read()  # Read the contents of the file
convert_lowercase = file_content.lower()  # No need to convert each line individually.
file_input.close()  # Close the file
for punctuation in string.punctuation:  # Go through the punctuation and replace it with an empty string (remove it) in your content.
    convert_lowercase.replace(punctuation, "")

with open("yelp.dat", "w") as file:
    file.write(convert_lowercase)  # This overwrites all current content that is inside the file.
```

Comment: thank you! that was so much clearer to understand!
so i tried adding this to it but it still didn't remove it. sorry for the many questions

     convert_lowercase.replace(".", "")

Comment: @DarrenGoh thats strange. Are you sure the character in your document is a standard period?

Comment: is there anyway to upload a file over here? i'm going crazy and i have no idea whats wrong

Comment: @DarrenGoh you can edit your question to provide the contents of the file

Comment: thank you! I added a part of the content as it is super long. basically i'm trying to clean up the file before i start to analyse the word occurrence frequency. no idea why i can't get rid of the punctuation or symbols. thank for helping me, much appreciated!!